# Bluetooth with Moto G4

Tags: bluetooth-hsp

I recently purchased a Motorola Moto G4. My husband has the LG wireless headphones. I tried to pair but every time I would get a phone call the voices would come over garbled like they were under water. I thought it was the headsets due to I also fought this with my last phone LG Phenix 2, so i went and bought another pair. These are called Warrior BT2. When I finished charging them up i paired them and made a phone call, same problem. i was ok as long as i held the phone but if i even went 1 ft from the phone it would cause issues. Where i live I don't have great service so when i find service i have to leave my phone in that spot. What can I do to fix this or do I need to go purchase the higher end ear phones? my husband's was 70 dollars and i still fight this. Please help

Comment: As a quick Google search will confirm, the Moto G4 series was notorious for the Bluetooth quality being poor, especially with BLE capable device, and also interference from WiFi... Does the problem get better if you disable WiFi on the device?

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. I didn't know about the Wifi. I will try that and let you know

Comment: Yeah, on the 2nd gen Moto G you couldn't use BLE at all while Wi-Fi was working. Getting all these radios to work at once without interfering is a tricky engineering problem, and it looks like Motorola just doesn't have those skills.